# Recommendations for a graphics library for real-time display of geospatial data

Tags: data-analysis, display, real-time

I'm looking for recommendations on graphics libraries or game engines that would facilitate semi-realtime plotting or playback of local cartesian or geospatial data. Here are some details on use case and constraints:

- Use Cases:

  - Real time display of an ongoing simulation that's generating data for consumption by the system I'm looking to create.
  - Playback and analysis of recorded data generated by the previously mentioned scenario.
  - Display of different data relations, e.g. Points 1-1024 belong to category A and are grouped for user interaction (colorization, hiding from view, etc.)
- Constraints:

  - Configurable quality to allow for low resource requirements (can run on a potato PC)
  - Library/SDKs are open source
  - Display data sources are configurable (can be SQL database, binary file, udp messages, etc.)
- Nice to Haves:

  - Inherently cross platform (windows or linux)
  - APIs are for C++, C#, or Python

Some things I've considered so far from my research have been:

- ROS and Rviz

  - Pros: Middleware helps with data source abstraction, supports common geospatial interactions (translations, rotations, etc.), ROS2 is cross platform
  - Cons: Middleware and ROS setup can be complex. I haven't worked with distributing a ROS based program to end users before.
- OpenGL

  - I'm not too familiar with directly interfacing with OpenGL, but my understanding is that I would have to essentially build an application around it/using it? It seems like everything from data inputs to user interactions would have to be self-made.
- Game Engine (Unity or Unreal)

  - I have no experience with these, but clearly they're able to provide the performance necessary. I assume the deciding factor would be how useful the provided tools are for this use case.

Thank you for any advice you're able to offer!

edit: Spelling/typos